# Do we want festive headwear?

Tags: discussion

> Due to the support shown by the community, we are signed up to participate in Winter Bash.
>
> If you have questions about the hats, please [ask them here](https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) or on [Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com).

Original post:

---

[Winter Bash 2015](http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/) is fast approaching, and we need to decide whether we want the honor of wearing hats.

#### The Details

This year's event will start on **14 December 2015** and run up to and including 03 January 2016. You'll be able to see all the hats you've earned on http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com:

[image]

If you don’t want to participate, don’t want to see hats, and/or are generally anti-hat, there will be an “I hate hats” option available. And just like last time, at the end of the event, all hats will go back into storage.

The only visual change to the site itself will be the presence of the hats and the “I hate hats” button in the footer.

If we *don't* want hats, **we need to know by 10 December 2015**.

So, what say you?

Answer (score 13):

We want hard wear!

[image: hard hat]

But soft wear needs to go to our [sister site](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

[image: no Hufflepuff Hat]

<sub>Credits: [hard hat](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Hard_hat_20111111.jpg) by [産業用保護帽](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%98%E3%83%AB%E3%83%A1%E3%83%83%E3%83%88) (public domain); interdicted soft hat derived from [knitted bobble hat photo](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Hufflepuff_Hat.jpg) by [anneheathen](http://www.flickr.com/people/52066925@N00) ([CC BY 2.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/2.0/deed.en)).</sub>

Comment: +1 for the great humor.

Answer (score 2):

WinterBash hats are fun.

In addition to being fun, it also helps in improving the participation of users in the site, especially because you don't know which hat you'd be getting for a particular participation.

So, it would have a festive look + a enthusiastic, active community.

So, a +1 for the WinterBash!